# Encrypting AND decrypting a string into a shorter hash (not for security)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, encryption

I've been playing around with a little [HTML tester](http://hexagonest.tk/code/?code=%3Cscript%3E%0D%0Afunction%20replace%28str%29%7B%0D%0A%20%20document.write%28str%29;%20//capable%20of%20JS%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%3C/script%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstyle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%2a%7Bbackground-color%3alightgray;%7D%20/%2acapable%20of%20CSS%2a/%0D%0A%3C/style%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cbutton%20type=%22button%22%20onclick=%22replace%28%27hello%27%29%22%3EHi!%3C/button%3E%0D%0A%3C!--and%20events%0D%0Ayou%20can%20also%20share!%0D%0Abut,%20the%20problem%20is%20the%20URL%27s%20are%20way%20too%20long!%0D%0A--%3E), that has a cool function to share. This redirects you to the shared URL. The problem is, the URL is WAY too long! Is there a way I can shorten these variable values?

I can md5() a string, and that will create a much shorter string, but I need a way to decrypt it. This is not for security purposes, it's purely for aesthetics.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Encrypting a string generally makes it longer, not shorter. MD5 is for checking the integrity of a string / file. IE take a md5 hash of a file before and after the download. If both are the same, the file was downloaded fine.

Comment: Let's say the string was "Hello, my name is John Doe! I like pie, and I have 30 cats!", would there be a way to shorten this while keeping its original value?

Comment: No. Not unless you use some kind of storage mechanism, like @developerwjk is suggesting below. It would be impossible to shorten, as as it is at the moment, it is exactly the minimum length required for me to understand it.

Comment: Have a look at http://tinyurl.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way: Make a table in a database.  Put in it one field for the original string, and one for the md5 hash.  When you receive in an md5 hash, lookup the original string from the table.  The problem is, what if two strings match the md5 hash??

So, it would be better for your purpose (just making a shorter reference to long urls) to just generate a random string (of a certain length) per original input and associate it to the original by inserting it into a table where the random string has a unique contraint.

```
create table reftable (original varchar(500), shortened varchar(20) unique);
```

Comment: It would be a little inconvenient having to make a new database entry for every click of share, right?

Comment: If you're lazy, then sure.

Comment: So, in short, there's no other way to do this?

Comment: On mssql you could use NEWID() which gives you a 36-byte GUID supposedly guaranteed to always be unique on your machine. But you still need a db.